# How to set a project working directory in a UI with wxWidgets?

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm a newbie at wxWidgets. I'm working with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I have a UI, which needs to take some files as input and outputs other files as results. I want the user to specify a "working directory" so that the program will put the output files into this directory. So I want to take the path from the user using a browse screen, and save that path and use it while defining my output file locations in the code.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why can't you just append the path to the files? You can also try chdir() or _chdir()

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the method you suggest? Can I use relative path instead of absolute paths with your advise?

Comment: Well, let's say your path is in a string called path, and your file name is in a string file_name. Then you make a new string, like full_file_name and you combine the two (via strcat and strcpy) and use that new string to save each file.

Comment: Thank you Radu, I managed the issue using strcat & strcpy.

Comment: Glad I could help. You might also look into the chdir() method, it is used to change the current directory. Although if the in and out files are in different directories, this won't help much.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the comment of Radu: you can use the DirDialog (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_dir_dialog.html) to get the directory from the user, than save that in a variable and prepend to the file names. You can then also store this directory in a configuration, using wxConfig (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_config_base.html) and load that value at program startup so the program remembers the working directory from session to session.